# What is HTTP Module in ASP.NET, How they are different from Filters in Asp.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I googled a lot about HTTP module but not get any clear understanding about HTTP module.

Can anyone please help me to understand, What is HTTP Module in asp.net? How they differ from filters in ASP.NET MVC

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this question really lacks specifics. Internet is full of info about HTTP modules, starting with [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178468.aspx). Do you have any specific questions about them?

Answer (score 2):

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx)

> An HTTP module is an assembly that is called on every request that is
>   made to your application. HTTP modules are called as part of the
>   request pipeline and have access to life-cycle events throughout the
>   request. HTTP modules therefore let you examine incoming requests and
>   take action based on the request. They also let you examine the
>   outgoing response and modify it.

Actually you use it when you make something that you like to distribute it and use it by many sites.

For example this HTTP Module can help [switching between HTTP and HTTPS automcatically](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5523/Switching-Between-HTTP-and-HTTPS-Automatically). You just add it to your site and make the setup inside the web.config.

Comment: How is it different from Filters?

Comment: @MohitDagar The module is called to the hart of the running cycle every time. Filters called base on user actions. Filters are MVC part, the http module is work for both MVC or forms

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. As I understood from your comment that. HTTP module run every time when we request any page of an application and Filter runs page request bases. a filter will run only when it is implemented on a controller. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.